# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Ruby 3.0 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.4.4 - 100.0 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Another amazing day today for all of us :)

I am trying to use the AWS EB Ruby 3.0 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.4.4 with a Ruby-on-Rails v6.0.4.4 app, but until now, I did not manage to make it work

In env status I get:

```
100.0 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx
```

also in /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
[error] 2459#2459: *596 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.34.113, server: _, request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/", host: "52.29.66.93"
```

and in /var/log/puma/puma.log

```
[4898] ! Unable to start worker
[4898] /opt/rubies/ruby-3.0.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.0.0/bundler/runtime.rb:309:in `check_for_activated_spec!'
[4898] Early termination of worker
```

The `pumactl` it looks ok

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-xx-xx ~]$ pumactl -V
5.6.2
```

If I check the processes:

```
ps aux | grep puma
    healthd  25925  0.0  3.6 828800 36624 ?        Ssl  09:39   0:15 puma 5.3.2 (tcp://127.0.0.1:22221) [healthd]
    webapp   26497  0.2  2.2 255768 22912 ?        Ss   09:40   1:07 puma 5.6.2 (unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock) [current]
    webapp   28653 64.0  2.1 327180 21668 ?        Rl   16:08   0:00 puma: cluster worker 0: 26497 [current]
    ec2-user 28656  0.0  0.0 119420   924 pts/0    S+   16:08   0:00 grep --color=auto puma
```

So the puma is running... correct?

Also, there is another puma v5.3.2

Maybe this other puma version is used for another reason (health service)?

In the Rails app I have the following:

.ebextensions/02_yarn.config

```
commands:

  01_node_get:
    cwd: /tmp
    command: 'curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo bash -'
  02_node_install:
    cwd: /tmp
    command: 'yum -y install nodejs'
  03_yarn_get:
    cwd: /tmp
    # don't run the command if yarn is already installed (file /usr/bin/yarn exists)
    test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/yarn ] && echo "yarn not installed"'
    command: 'sudo wget https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo'
  04_yarn_install:
    cwd: /tmp
    test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/yarn ] && echo "yarn not installed"'
    command: 'sudo yum -y install yarn'
  05_mkdir_webapp_dir:
    command: "mkdir /home/webapp"
    ignoreErrors: true
  06_chown_webapp_dir:
    command: "chown webapp:webapp /home/webapp"
    ignoreErrors: true
  07_chmod_webapp_dir:
    command: "chmod 0744 /home/webapp"
    ignoreErrors: true
  08_chmod_logs:
    command: "chown webapp:webapp -R /var/app/current/log/"
    ignoreErrors: true
  09_create_log_file:
    command: "touch /var/app/current/log/production.log"
    ignoreErrors: true
  10_chown_log_production:
    command: "chown webapp:webapp /var/app/current/log/production.log"
    ignoreErrors: true
  11_chmod_log_dir:
    command: "chmod 0664 -R /var/app/current/log/"
    ignoreErrors: true
  12_update_bundler:
    command: "gem update bundler"
    ignoreErrors: true
  13_chown_current:
    command: "chown webapp:webapp -R /var/app/current/"
    ignoreErrors: true
  14_chmod_current:
    command: "chmod 0755 -R /var/app/current/"
    ignoreErrors: true
  15_chown_current:
    command: "chown webapp:webapp -R /var/app/ondeck/"
    ignoreErrors: true
  16_chown_current:
    command: "chmod 0644 -R /var/app/ondeck/"
    ignoreErrors: true

container_commands:

  17_install_webpack:
    command: "npm install --save-dev webpack"
  18_precompile:
    command: "bundle exec rake assets:precompile"
```

.ebextensions/03_nginx.config

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/02_app_server.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      # The content of this file is based on the content of /etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp_healthd.conf

      # Change the name of the upstream because it can't have the same name
      # as the one defined by default in /etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp_healthd.conf
      upstream new_upstream_name {
        server unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
      }

      # Change the name of the log_format because it can't have the same name
      # as the one defined by default in /etc/nginx/conf.d/webapp_healthd.conf
      log_format new_log_name_healthd '$msec"$uri"'
                      '$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"'
                      '$http_x_forwarded_for';

      server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _ localhost; # need to listen to localhost for worker tier

        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
          set $year $1;
          set $month $2;
          set $day $3;
          set $hour $4;
        }

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
        # Match the name of log_format directive which is defined above
        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour new_log_name_healthd;

        location / {
          # Match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
          proxy_pass http://new_upstream_name;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /assets {
          alias /var/app/current/public/assets;
          gzip_static on;
          gzip on;
          expires max;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        location /public {
          alias /var/app/current/public;
          gzip_static on;
          gzip on;
          expires max;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
        }

        location /packs {
          alias /var/app/current/public/packs;
          gzip_static on;
          gzip on;
          expires max;
          add_header Cache-Control public;
        }
      }

container_commands:
  01_restart_nginx:
    command: "sudo service nginx reload"
```

Any ideas why it is not working?

In the `.ebextensions/03_nginx.config` there is in the `files` section an entry for `/etc/nginx/conf.d/02_app_server.conf`, but there is no such file:

```
ls -ls /etc/nginx/conf.d/
total 8
0 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  45 Apr  8 15:42 elasticbeanstalk
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62 Apr  8 15:42 elasticbeanstalk-nginx-ruby-upstream.conf
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 147 Apr  8 15:42 healthd_logformat.conf
```

Is this OK?

Thank you very much in advance for your kind help and support and for your valuable time

I wish to all of us all the best and an amazing continuation in our lives...

Comment: Dear @lacostenycoder,
Thank you for your notice of possible duplicate,
but as you can see, this question has not been resolved, no answer at all, only two comments
Do you think that it was necessary to mention this possible duplication?

Comment: fair point, removing comment

Comment: Dear @lacostenycoder,
thank you very much :)
I wish to you and to all of Us all the best :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `Amazon Linux 2` your nginx settings will never work. This is because they are for AL1, but you are using AL2. All your nginx settings should be defined through  `.platform/nginx/conf.d/`, NOT `.ebextentions` as explained in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

Comment: Dear @Marcin,
thank you for your kind reply,
yes you are correct.
Is there somewhere a working example of how can I use the new way?
Thank you again for your kind help and time

Comment: @aAon-AndreasP.Gortsilas No problem. Its in the docs I linked in the answer.